# Cancelling alarm using AlarmManager

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-notifications, android-alarms

I'm developing an reminder app, in which I store all the reminder
related data in the database using sqlite, everything is working fine.

**Problem:**

When I delete the row from the database I'm also trying to turn the
alarm off, but it's not working, I'm using recyclerview.

Please help me to find out what's wrong in my code.

Here's my Code:

**DataAdapter.java**

```
dataAdapterViewHolder.deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int deleteRowId = context.getContentResolver().delete(RoutineContract.RoutinesEntry.CONTENT_URI,
                    rowSelection, rowSelectionArgs);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent alertIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, rowId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
            if(alertIntent != null) {
                alarmManager.cancel(alertIntent);
                alertIntent.cancel();
                Log.e("row id", ""+rowId);
            }
        }
    });
```

**AddReminderActivity.java**

```
            Uri insertUri = getContentResolver().insert(RoutineContract.RoutinesEntry.CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
            int rowId = Integer.parseInt(insertUri.getLastPathSegment());

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
            intent.setData(insertUri);
            intent.putExtra("name", name);
            intent.putExtra("repeatType", repeatType);
            PendingIntent alertIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, rowId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, dateTime.getTimeInMillis(),
            pendingIntent);
```

P.S.: I have already searched on stackoverflow and found solutions for the problem but none is working for me right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you check if the alarmintent already exists with this code  `PendingIntent alertIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, rowId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);` you pass the flag `PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE`, that returns `null` if it finds one, you can read more [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_NO_CREATE).
Try instead passing `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`

*EDIT*: I tried scheduling and canceling an alarm with a code similar to yours and it seems to work, the main differences are the Intent passed to the `getBroadcast` function and the flag i use to get the `pendingIntent`, in both cases `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`. I used the code below

```
public void scheduleAlarm() {
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(mContext, ScheduledActionReceiver.class);
        notificationIntent.setAction(ACTION_NOTIFICATION);

        long now = System.currentTimeMillis() + 5 * 1000;

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, Constants.ALARM_ID, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, now, pendingIntent);
}
public void removeAlarm() {
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(mContext, ScheduledActionReceiver.class);
        notificationIntent.setAction(ACTION_NOTIFICATION);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, Constants.ALARM_ID, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
}
```

*EDIT 1*: I think i finally figured it out, with a couple more tests i noticed that if put this lines of code
 `notificationIntent.setData(Uri.parse("uri to parse"));`

when i schedule the alarm, the cancel action doesn't work if i don't put it also when retrieving it before canceling it (on the other hand setting extras doesn't seem to make any difference)

Comment: I have tried with FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT and FLAG_ONE_SHOT too, but that doesn't worked for me

Comment: Please see my edited answer and try adding setData(yourUri) also when canceling the alarm

Comment: thanks that worked, it's mentioned in the docs that cancel pendingIntent should match with one used at the time of creating, I forgot that.